# Display details of `ItemKey` in a row from the JSON response

Tags: c#, group-by, blazor

I have a table, `Item`, which stores key/value pairs. So my JSON returns key-value pairs.
Key can be of three types: 'Item Name', 'Location', and 'Date'.

Model:

```cs
public class Item
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string ItemKey { get; set; }
    public string Key { get; set; } // Key can be of three types `'Item Name', 'Location', 'Date'`
    public string Value { get; set; }       
}
```

How do I display all info of `ItemKey` on to one row, from the JSON? Grouping by `ItemKey`.

```
[
  {"id":"1","itemKey":"item1","key":"ItemName","value":"Apple"},
  {"id":"2","itemKey":"item2","key":"ItemName","value":"Orange"}, 
  {"id":"3","itemKey":"item1","key":"Location","value":"USA"},
  {"id":"4","itemKey":"item2","key":"Location","value":"Angola"},  
  {"id":"5","itemKey":"item2","key":"Date","value":"03.11.2022"}, 
  {"id":"6","itemKey":"item3","key":"ItemName","value":"Banana"},
  {"id":"7","itemKey":"item3","key":"Date","value":"24.10.2022"}
]
```

I would like to display each `itemKey` detail in the razor page as below:

For eg: Grouping by item1 would return:

> itemKey -  Item1, itemName - Apple, Location -USA (date is not available for item1)

```
<thead>
    <tr>
    <th>ItemKey</th>     
    <th>ItemName</th>
    <th>Location</th>
    <th>Date</th>    
    </tr>
</thead>
```

The current code is below for reference:

Below gets me list of items from the JSON

ItemService.cs:

```cs
public async Task<List<FecMetaDatum>> GetItems()
{
    return await _httpClient.GetFromJsonAsync<List<Item>>("api/Item");
}
```

Index.razor:

```
@foreach (var r in items)
{         
    <tr>
        <td>@r.id</td>     
        <td>@r.itemKey</td>
        <td>@r.key</td>
        <td>@r.value</td>    
    </tr>
}
   
protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
{
    items= await ItemService.GetItems();
}
```

Comment: have you tried `_httpClient.GetFromJsonAsync<List<Item>>("api/Item").GroupBy(z => z.ItemKey).ToList()` ?

Comment: Thank you. Says Task<List<Item>?>does not contain a definition for 'GroupBy' and no accessible extension method 'GroupBy' accepting a first argument of type  Task<List<Item>?>

Comment: Have you added using System.Linq; ?

Comment: Using System.Linq already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you know that the response will return either of three different keys for the `key` property. You need to [`.GroupBy()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.groupby?view=net-7.0) from *System.Linq* to group `ItemKey` and extract each `key` and `value` as below:

1. Create a `DisplayItem` class for the grouped result instance.

```cs
public class DisplayItem
{
    public string ItemKey { get; set; }
    public string ItemName { get; set; }
    public string Location { get; set; }
    public string Date { get; set; }
}
```

2. `.GroupBy()` `ItemKey`, extract each `key` and `value` pair by first `key` via `.FirstOrDefault()`. Use `?.` null conditional operator for handling in case the parsed key doesn't exist.

```cs
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

List<DisplayItem> items = new ();

protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
{
    items = (await ItemService.GetItems())
        .GroupBy(x => x.ItemKey)
        .Select(x => new DisplayItem
        {
            ItemKey = x.Key,
            ItemName = x.FirstOrDefault(y => y.Key == "ItemName")?.Value,
            Location = x.FirstOrDefault(y => y.Key == "Location")?.Value,
            Date = x.FirstOrDefault(y => y.Key == "Date")?.Value
        })
        .ToList();
}
```

3. Modify the View for displaying respective properties.

```
@foreach (var r in items)
{ 
    <tr>
        <td>@r.ItemKey</td>     
        <td>@r.ItemName</td>
        <td>@r.Location</td>
        <td>@r.Date</td>    
    </tr>
}
```

[Demo Concept @ .NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/FM8iHB)

Comment: I want date as DateTime instead of string. Tried this line:  date = Convert.ToDateTime(x.FirstOrDefault(y => y.Key == "Date")?.Value). But says String '26.10.2022 02:07:45' was not recognized as a valid DateTime. I would appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: You can't directly assign a `string` value to `DateTime` type. You need to convert it via [`DateTime.ParseExact()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.parseexact?view=net-7.0). [Demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/1M81il)

Comment: Tried this for int. And this works too. Thanks a lot.   No = x.FirstOrDefault(y => y.Key == "no")?.Value != null
                    ? int.Parse(x.FirstOrDefault(y => y.Key == "no")?.Value)
                    : (int?)null,

Comment: Is it possible to convert the DateTime in the fiddle to this format '2022-11-17T00:00:00'. As datepicker I use returns in this format, Date from query and Date from datepicker need to be compared and returned true (if both dates are same). Time can be ignored. Rite now fiddle query returns this format '2022-11-17T10:15:30+03:00'. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I modified your class according to your table header. Then I used `JAarray` by NewtonSoft to get individual json objects and update the item list with the values according to the key in the object.

Implementation:

```razor
@page "/"
@using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq

<table class="table table-striped mb-0">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>ItemKey</th>
        <th>ItemName</th>
        <th>Location</th>
        <th>Date</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    @if (items != null)
    {
        @foreach (var r in items)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>@r.ItemKey</td>
                <td>@r.ItemName</td>
                <td>@r.Location</td>
                <td>@r.Date</td>
            </tr>
        }
    }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

```cs
@code {
    readonly string json = "[{\"id\":\"1\",\"itemKey\":\"item1\",\"key\":\"ItemName\",\"value\":\"Apple\"},\r\n{\"id\":\"2\",\"itemKey\":\"item2\",\"key\":\"ItemName\",\"value\":\"Orange\"}, \r\n{\"id\":\"3\",\"itemKey\":\"item1\",\"key\":\"Location\",\"value\":\"USA\"},\r\n{\"id\":\"4\",\"itemKey\":\"item2\",\"key\":\"Location\",\"value\":\"Angola\"},  \r\n{\"id\":\"5\",\"itemKey\":\"item2\",\"key\":\"Date\",\"value\":\"03.11.2022\"}, \r\n{\"id\":\"6\",\"itemKey\":\"item3\",\"key\":\"ItemName\",\"value\":\"Banana\"},\r\n{\"id\":\"7\",\"itemKey\":\"item3\",\"key\":\"Date\",\"value\":\"24.10.2022\"}]";

    List<Item> items = new List<Item>();

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        var jArray = JArray.Parse(json);

        foreach (JObject item in jArray)
        {
            var itemKey =  item.GetValue("itemKey").ToString();
            
            // add new item into list if itemkey not exist
            if (items.All(x => x.ItemKey != itemKey))
                items.Add(new Item(){ItemKey = itemKey});

            var index = items.FindIndex(x => x.ItemKey == itemKey);
            
            // update respective values according to key
            var propertyInfo = items[index].GetType().GetProperty(item.GetValue("key").ToString());
            if (propertyInfo != null)
                propertyInfo.SetValue(items[index], item.GetValue("value").ToString());
        }
    }

    public class Item
    {
        public string ItemKey { get; set; }
        public string ItemName { get; set; }
        public string Location { get; set; }
        public string Date { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Result:
[image: Blazor table json]